# What sort of errors can lead to session data being exposed across different computers?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, load-balancing

I'm experiencing a strange error with my cakePHP application. The users to this application occasionally are authenticated incorrectly and are able to view a different user's profile information on their page. I know this is a very open ended question, and without code should be hard to get a specific answer, but I'm wondering what sort of general problems could lead to this sort of behavior, and if anyone on SO could lead me in the right direction. It seems like it should be a common enough problem, but I can't find any literature about it.

My application is behind a load balancer, which might have the potential for weird behavior with the session, but I'm under the impression that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random thoughts:

- Are you using caching? Maybe some cache gets refreshed somewhere with user-specific data, but gets stored as the new result for every user. It could be as simple as a missing cache ID parameter somewhere.
- Consider setting up a  process that allows users  to file a report that gets automatically filled with the data you need for debugging: Session ID, IP, request URL, time of the request...
- Other than that: I don't have much experience with them, but a load balancer sounds like an obvious culprit when user specific data gets mixed up. Consider giving more information about your setup.

Comment: Thank You. Yeah, I'm caching view files on the application level, as well as caching content on the load balancer. But I don't believe I'm caching any of my queries or anything like that. It is definitely the actual session that is incorrect and not simply a cached view, because I am able to log the session. Not sure if this helps or not.

Comment: @Nick I'd say then the load balancer is the most likely culprit. I can't think of a way to mix up sessions in a normal PHP setup at all (unless you force new session IDs somewhere using `session_id()` and something goes wrong)

Comment: Definitely not forcing new session IDs. It seems like the load balancer is improperly implementing session persistence. Thanks!